# Repeating pattern in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, css, translate-animation

How would I repeat the transform pattern below?

```
BoxesFx.prototype._setTransforms = function() {
    this.transforms = {
        'effect-1' : {
            'next' : [
                'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', 
                'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', 
                'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', 
            ],
            'prev' : [
                'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
                'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)',
                'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)'
            ]
        }}}
```

Basically, I am trying to have :

```
'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', 
'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', 
'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)'
```

repeat n amount of times, we can say n will be 3, without copying and pasting it in 3 times. Is there a way to duplicate an array? I feel like I may be confusing.. hope I explained it well

Comment: This seems like something that should be handled with CSS. I'd need to double check but I think the browsers that support `translate3d` also support `calc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the array outside

```
var translate =[
   'translate3d(0, ' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', 
   'translate3d(-' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)', 
   'translate3d(' + (win.width/2+10) + 'px, 0, 0)',
   'translate3d(0, -' + (win.height/2+10) + 'px, 0)', 
];

BoxesFx.prototype._setTransforms = function() {
    this.transforms = {
        'effect-1' : {
            'next' : translate,
            'prev' : translate
        }}}
```

The two arrays you have aren't the same, but I'm assuming they could be, as you can't reference an array twice and get two completely different arrays ?

If you need an actual new copy of the array each time, you can do

```
'next' : translate.slice(0)
```

instead

Comment: thanks for your response. But i think I am still confused how I would get the pattern to repeat 5 times for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question? It's just arrays, you define the array somewhere and reference it as many times as you want without having to type it more than once, but it has to be the same array, you can't duplicate different patterns ?

Comment: I have this variable amount that I want to be flexible and can return anything depend on how many images are uploaded                          var panelamt = document.querySelectorAll('#boxgallery .panel').length;  I want the pattern to repeat panelamt times no matter what number it returns